# ImportError: cannot import name 'types' from 'google.cloud.vision' though I have google cloud vision installed

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pip, google-cloud-vision

I have installed google-cloud-vision library following the documentation. It is for some reason unable to import `types` from `google.cloud.vision`. It worked fine on my pc, now when I shared with my client, he had a problem with imports though he has the library installed via pip. Here's the line that throws error:

```py
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types # this line throws error
```

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: 1) What version of the libraries and which ones are installed? 2) What is the exact error message? 3) Which Python version is installed on both systems? 4) Run the command `pip freeze` on both systems and compare the libraries installed. Edit your question to include these details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably because there's some version mismatch (or less likely there's other library(s) with the same name). Have your client use a virtual environment. This should resolve the issue.

P.S. You'll have to provide him with a `requirements.txt` file (obtained from `pip3 freeze`) so that he can do a `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` on his virtual environment to have the exact same packages as yours.

Comment: Can you create a new virtual env in your own system and run?

Comment: I created a virtual environment but that didn't solve the issue, it for some reason was still pointing to the old versions. 
I used `requirements.text` file to install it but still no luck. 
> Uninstalled google-cloud-vision
> Then I uninstalled python
> Reinstalled it. 
> Installed modules again using `pip install -r requirements.txt`
> The modules that were still missing (for any reason), I installed them with the same version as mine (for instance `pip install google-cloud-vision==1.0.0`) 
# I found that version (i.e 1.0.0) from my requirements.txt file.
That resolved my issue.

Comment: Still pointing to old versions? You sure you successfully sourced the venv and not just create it? Anyways, glad to know things worked out :D

Answer (score 27):

Use `from google.cloud.vision_v1 import types` instead of `from google.cloud.vision import types`.[I have get this by  exploring the init.py file and it works.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhMej.png)

Answer (score 12):

Types module has been removed from google.cloud.vision from 2.0.0. You can access all the types from vision.

https://googleapis.dev/python/vision/latest/UPGRADING.html#enums-and-types

Before:

```
from google.cloud import vision_v1

likelihood = vision_v1.enums.Likelihood.UNKNOWN
request = vision_v1.types.GetProductSetRequest(name="name")
```

After:

```
from google.cloud import vision_v1

likelihood = vision_v1.Likelihood.UNKNOWN
request = vision_v1.GetProductSetRequest(name="name")
```